# Is the megaraptor's Fortitude saving throw correct?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, saving-throw, animals, errata

I'm trying to understand whether this is an error, or whether there is something I'm missing.

According to the System Reference Document, a [megaraptor](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dinosaur.htm#megaraptor)'s Fort save is +10.

As an 8 hit dice animal, its base save is +6 because Fort is a Good save for it, and it gains a +5 bonus on its Fort save due to its Con of 21; therefore, its total Fort save bonus should be +11.

I also checked the D&D 3.5 *Monster Manual* errata, and I noticed that the megaraptor has been amended, but nothing I can find resolves this particular issue. Its size was amended from Huge to Large; however, this hasn't affected its Con bonus, as both in the errata and an unrevised 3.5 *Monster Manual*, it is listed as 21 (+5). Its HD are also both the same.

Is the megaraptor's Fortitude saving throw correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It's incorrect

This is, indeed, an error. As the question points out, the [megaraptor](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDitoDo.html#megaraptor-dinosaur) (*Monster Manual* 60–1) should have a Fortutide saving throw bonus of +11. This error remains uncorrected by the premium edition *Monster Manual* (2012) that incorporates the errata that makes the megaraptor instead size Large. [*Cooper's Compendium A–D*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935050273) agrees that the megaraptor's Fortitude saving throw is an error, saying

> The megaraptor was downgraded, via official errata, from a Huge animal to a Large one. The changes I [i.e. the author of the *Compendium*, not the one writing this answer] made to the creature’s stats [in the *Compendium*] all stem from this change in size, with one exception: I bumped its Fortitude save up from +10 to +11 (it gets +6 as an 8-HD animal and +5 from its Constitution). (93)

So you know, *Cooper's Compendium* corrects most of the *Monster Manual* creatures that need correction. (Many, many do!) While the *Compendium* does still gloss over some gray areas (see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98195/8610), for example), it addresses many of the *Monster Manual*'s minor oversights like this one. I'm not associated with *Cooper's Compendium*, but I recommend it to any DM for whom customizing monsters is serious business.

Comment: Serious business is what we do.

Comment: @MichaelDorf I think you mean bunsiness